# Order values based on their 'IN' order - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, sql-order-by

I have an array which is already sorted using one of it's properties (weight). I'm then using this same array inside a query to get the number of attributes each 'object' matches.

```
SELECT objectattributelink.ID, COUNT(*) Attributes
FROM objectattributelink, attributelist
WHERE objectattributelink.ID = attributelist.AttributeID
AND attributelist.AttributeDesc IN ('Solid', 'Metal', 'Red', 'AB', 'Blue', 'Liquid', 'Plastic')
AND objectattributelink.AttributeID IN ('".implode("', '", $myArray)."')
GROUP BY objectattributelink.ID
ORDER BY Attributes DESC, Order of ID's inside 'IN' Clause DESC
```

I'm trying to sort this array on two levels:

- Primary (Most Important): By the number of attributes they match (already done in query)
- Secondary: Following the order in which the ID's appear inside the 'IN' clause (so they maintain their weight order within each 'number of attributes' group)

The second one is the one I'm having problems with. Been thinking about using cases, but since the array length varies (2-100) this is not an option.

NOTE: The pre-ordering (by weight) is done using an Ajax cross-domain call to get the data from other server, so doing everything inside this query is not possible.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Thanks Gordon for your answer on my other question, worked perfectly. I'm basically doing the same thing here, but want this SQL query to return sorting on two levels. I'm actually using the query you suggested me for the Attribute sorting. [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18244765/order-grouped-values-by-custom-rank-sql[7link](I'm using this simplified version of the query for this question. Same DB as last time, but now picking a custom array of ID's)

Comment: You're aware that this comment is not of use to any people that are not @Mazka, right? :) Could you maybe link to your previous, related question? – inflagranti 12 mins ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues. First of all, you cannot order by columns that do no appear in the group by. Second, you would have to create an ad-hoc table instead of the in. For the later something like this should work:

```
SELECT objectattributelink.ID, COUNT(*) Attributes
FROM objectattributelink, attributelist, TABLE (VALUES ('Solid', 1), ('Metal', 2), ('Red', 3), ('AB', 4), ('Blue', 5), ('Liquid', 6), ('Plastic', 7)) AS descs(AttributeDesc, AttributeNo)
WHERE objectattributelink.ID = attributelist.AttributeID
AND attributelist.AttributeDesc = descs.AttributeDesc
AND objectattributelink.AttributeID IN ('".implode("', '", $myArray)."')
GROUP BY objectattributelink.ID
ORDER BY Attributes DESC, descs.AttributeNo
```

However, this is still not valid since the `descs.AttributeNo` column is not in the group by. Also I'm not sure any DB other than DB2 supports this...

So to fix the group by issue, you would have to change your group by to:

```
GROUP BY objectattributelink.ID, descs.AttributeNo
```

This should not change the grouping itself, since ID implies the attributeno.

Also, I'm not sure, but you might also have to change your order by to:

```
ORDER BY 2 DESC, descs.AttributeNo
```

So the final query would look like this:

```
SELECT objectattributelink.ID, COUNT(*) Attributes
FROM objectattributelink, attributelist, TABLE (VALUES ('Solid', 1), ('Metal', 2), ('Red', 3), ('AB', 4), ('Blue', 5), ('Liquid', 6), ('Plastic', 7)) AS descs(AttributeDesc, AttributeNo)
WHERE objectattributelink.ID = attributelist.AttributeID
AND attributelist.AttributeDesc = descs.AttributeDesc
AND objectattributelink.AttributeID IN ('".implode("', '", $myArray)."')
GROUP BY objectattributelink.ID
ORDER BY 2 DESC, descs.AttributeNo
```

Finally, you could also use row_number to not have to explicitly put the numbers:

```
SELECT objectattributelink.ID, COUNT(*) Attributes
FROM objectattributelink, attributelist, 
     (SELECT AttributeDesc, row_number() over() AS AttributeNo FROM VALUES (('Solid'), ('Metal'), ('Red'), ('AB'), ('Blue'), ('Liquid'), ('Plastic')) AS (AttributeDesc)) AS descs
WHERE objectattributelink.ID = attributelist.AttributeID
AND attributelist.AttributeDesc = descs.AttributeDesc
AND objectattributelink.AttributeID IN ('".implode("', '", $myArray)."')
GROUP BY objectattributelink.ID
ORDER BY 2 DESC, descs.AttributeNo
```